# error in building tensorflow example ios code on mac os sierra

Tags: ios, c, xcode, tensorflow, macos-sierra

I am trying build the iOS app detailed in https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/

but it fails with:

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in /projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/protobuf':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.  
If you meant to cross compile, use '--host'.  
See 'config.log' for more details.`
```

System details:
Mac OS Sierra 10.12

brew config output below : Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
MacBook-Pro:tensorflow $ brew config  
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.0.6
ORIGIN: https:/  
HEAD: 35ee2831086e923e7fcaf75fb440b01312e3f9c5  
Last commit: 7 days ago  
Core tap ORIGIN: https:/  
Core tap HEAD: 80f18defefc814d60d3799e58835cbeffc8e93c8  
Core tap last commit: 2 hours ago  
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local  
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar  
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https:/  
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell  
Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648  
Clang: 8.0 build 800  
Git: 2.8.4 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git  
Perl: /usr/bin/perl  
Python: /usr/bin/python  
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_60  
macOS: 10.12-x86_64  
Xcode: 8.0  
CLT: 8.0.0.0.1.1472435881  
X11: N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have homebrew installed, try **brew install libtool**, before anything. It should work.

Comment: I had ran into another error ,and installing libtool with the command above,  got rid of that error, then the build script ran for a while, and produced the error in my original post. still stumped, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on trying to setup tensorflow on MacOS Seirra.
Currently there are some issues building tensorflow for simulator and thus removing simulator dependencies from the scripts is the trick.

```
Try removing all occurences of X86_64 bits from the build scripts 
compile_ios_protobuf.sh & compile_ios_tensorflow.sh and then
run build_all_ios.sh
```

It works great on device.